# Disk changing to read-only by it self?

Tags: filesystem, windows-10, 18.04, read-only

I installed Ubuntu and Windows 10 on the same drive. I partitioned some space for Ubuntu, I use win10 to do some design-work(Adobe mainly) and download files.
It was fine last week but these days the part of disk I installed Windows became read-only, I cannot change the file names or unzip them, why does this happen and how can I fix it?